# php scripts as root user

Tags: php

Before anyone decides to tell me running php scripts as root is bad please read the next line carefully:

THIS IS A LAN ACCESS ONLY NO PUBLIC ACCESS.

now that said I'm trying to setup some php scripts to manage the lan dhcp server and a few other tasks and I have su php installed but not sure how to configure it to run the php files as root.

if anyone has done this before please guide me in allowing the scripts to run as root

Comment: +1 for the "Before anyone decides to tell me running php scripts as root is bad please read the next line carefully:"

Comment: Even in a LAN environment, whoever runs that script will have root access to the whole application. Are you sure PHP is the best route for what you plan to do? Shell scripting might be able to do the job as well.

Comment: Also: LAN access only does **not** mean you're home free -- malicious external sites can call your scripts via a user's browser. If some of your scripts are vulnerable to XSS/XSRF, it may be possible for an attacker to exploit this.

Comment: Disclosures aside, this really isn't a very good question. There aren't any specifics, there's no evidence of existing research or attempts, and we have no idea what the poster is stuck on. See the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What configuration have you tried so far?

Example configuration

http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=suphp.conf-example

Documentation

http://www.suphp.org/Documentation.html

You can also find information on how to setup for many linux distros on Google

Can you post more details, where are you struggling to setup it?